# MPPT solar buck charger - how does it sense when to change charge stage/regime

Tags: microcontroller, solar-cell, charger, mppt, sensing

I have a well-engineered MPPT buck solar charger that I am looking to repair; the schematic is unavailable.

The charger is unstable, and randomly changes what charge regime it's in.

Does anyone know (in general terms) how these types of chargers sense when to change charging regimes from Bulk to Absorption to Float?

It doesn't look like there is an obvious current shunt so I guess it must work off sensing the voltage? Is a Zener diode commonly used for that?

Any info or advice would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could be a voltage reference with a comparator, could be an ADC peripheral in a microcontroller, could be a dedicated voltage monitoring IC talking over I2C, or something else. No way of telling without some reverse-engineering to get the schematic, or maybe the type numbers of all ICs on the board.

Comment: Thanks Ocrdu - those are some good suggestions for me to begin investigating!

Comment: the two resistors below the right hand most mosfet/power device look like a shunt to me. if the unit is well-engineered, then why did it fail?